# GWT: Background screen does not load after the popup screen loads only in IE8

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8

I have a GWT application. There are 2 events fired after a button click. 1 event initializes the presenter of the main page and other initializes the presenter of popup screen. On all the browser except IE8 both the presenters are initialized and both the main page and popup are loaded fully. But in IE 8, the popup loads completely but the main page just shows loading progress bar.

```
//This event is handled in the presenter
                        eventBus.fetchSomeData(object1);
                        if(Condition1) {
                            //If the condition is met then trigger this event 
                            // and this event is handled in PopupPresenter
                            eventBus.fetchPopupData(POPUPPRESENTER, false);
                        }

                        class Presenter1 {
                            public onFetchSomeData(Object object1) {
                                // make some server calls
                                // On success, initialize the view.
                            }
                        }

                        class PopupPresenter {
                            public onFetchPopupData(Object object1) {
                                // make some server calls
                                // On success, initialize the view.
                            }
                        }
```

I see the following exception in developer tool:
[FATAL] Uncaught Exception:
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error) 
 number: -2146826178
description: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.

If i add a delay using timer between the two events, then the main page loads completely and then the popup page loads(ofcourse there is a delay which is not desirable). So I think if the popup page gets response from the server before the main page gets response from the server, popup page loads first and control is moved to popup page. So the main page is out of focus now and hence it cannot be loaded and the above error is thrown.

Does IE 8 handles events in a different way? What could be the possible reason? What is the best way to handle this.

Thank you for the help.

-jayash

Comment: Provide some code you are working with please